# Devextreme : Custom Formatter function inside format object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, devextreme

Here is JSON

```
var data = [
{ quarter: 'QI', quantity: 22226.252 },
{ quarter: 'QII', quantity: 26.5 }
];
```

and my JS Code

```
    column: {
        format: {
            type: 'fixedPoint',
            precision: 2,
            formatter: (data)=> {
              return data + ' ***ADDED**** '; // returning '22226.252 ***ADDED****' but this has to return '22,226.25 ***ADDED****' 
            }
        }
    }
}
};
```

Hi am new to Devextreme, formatter function not working. formatter function not applying format : {type, precision}.  need help...

My requirement is, I need to print **" 22,226.25 ***ADDED**** "** value

Comment: You need to format `quantity` as a string. There's likely to be many other questions which cover this.

Comment: not as a string, I need quantity+string

Comment: If you want a comma in your number, you need to format it first.

Comment: yes, comma needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toLocaleString](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp)

```
return data.toLocaleString() + ' ***ADDED**** ';
```